# Crontab script doesn't log

Tags: shell, logging, cron

```
#!/bin/bash

timestamp() {
 date +"%T"
}

getEntries() {
wc -l /etc/passwd
}

 echo "Scanned on":$( timestamp)and found:$( getEntries)"number of entries"|tee testlog.log
```

When I run this script manually the log file updates but when crontab runs it doesnt update the log file but the cront tab runs.

My crontab -e

```
* * * * * /testcron.sh
```

Comment: Where are you expecting that log file to be? Hint: It may not be where you expect. Use a full path.

Comment: When a `cron` job runs, you can't assume it runs from your home directory. So explicit full path names are recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give full path for output log file :

```
echo "Scanned on":$( timestamp)and found:$( getEntries)"number of entries" | 
tee /home/user/testlog.log
```

Now check `/home/user` directory.

Comment: i gave it a full path but my log file still doesnt update but i still get you have a new mail from the crontab.

Comment: Try to execute that command manually in terminal and check whether it creates file or not?

Comment: I did not add full path in the crontab thanks for your help!